# Embarcadero C++Builder failing to create pre-compiled headers

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo, jansson

We were migrating Jansson 2.7 to Jansson 2.14 in Embarcadero C++Builder. After successfully added to the project, we are getting the following error, which comes from Jansson -> `dump.c`:

> [bcc32 Error] dump.c(443): E2063 Illegal initialization

> ```
> size_t json_dumpb(const json_t *json, char *buffer, size_t size, size_t flags) {
>     struct buffer buf = {size, 0, buffer};  // <-- **Throws Error**
>
>     if (json_dump_callback(json, dump_to_buffer, (void *)&buf, flags))
>         return 0;
>
>     return buf.used;
> }
> ```

[image]

Comment: It's extremely confusing to have `char *buffer` and `struct buffer buf` in the same scope. You are not making  it fun for the maintenance crew :) What's the definition of `struct buffer`?

Comment: Have you tried simply renaming the `char *buffer` parameter?

Comment: I have tried changing the name of char *buffer . But getting the same error

Comment: You still haven't shown the definition of `struct buffer` which is sort of the main thing here since it's there you get the initialization error.